# From prototype to CSS Image positioning

Tags: html, css, user-interface, user-experience, figma

I am new to using Figma and am new to more complex styling in CSS, but I have made a prototype within Figma of a page that I am trying to build-out. I am having trouble on the side of taking the image and making it into the actual page. The Figma wireframe/prototype looks like this:

[image: Homepage prototype from Figma of fictional island in the Pacific.]

However, when I am building this out in HTML/CSS, I have been unsuccessful in obtaining a similar image positioning of the background image.

My HTML/CSS for this is as follows:

```css
:root {
  --menucolor: rgba(97, 124, 133, 1);
  --lighttext: rgba(240, 237, 232, 1);
  --darkgray: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  --darkerblue: rgba(27, 67, 89, 1);
  --headertext: 'Permanent Marker', cursive;
  --maintext: 'Nunito', sans-serif;
  --hovertext: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: var(--maintext);
  color: var(--darkerblue);
}

h1 {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.image-container {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.image-container::after {
  background-image: url('https://github.com/mcbraunie/IslandWebsite/blob/main/public/images/IslandPhotoLarge.png?raw=true');
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  transform: translate(25%, -50%);
  width: calc(100vh/2);
  height: 100vh;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
  background-position: center right;
  border-radius: 50%;
  z-index: -1;
}

.nav-container {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: var(--menucolor);
}

.navbar {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 0.2fr auto 1fr;
  align-items: center;
  height: 200px;
  width: 90%;
  max-width: 1720px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#nabbar-logo {
  color: var(--lighttext);
  justify-self: start;
  margin-left: 20px;
}

#navbar-logo {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.nav-menu {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(8, auto);
  list-style: none;
  text-align: center;
  width: 75%;
  justify-self: end;
}

.nav-links {
  color: var(--lighttext);
  text-decoration: none;
}

.nav-links:hover {
  color: var(--hovertext);
  transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
}

.menu-toggle .bar {
  width: 25px;
  height: 3px;
  margin: 5px auto;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  background: var(--lighttext);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Karla&family=Nunito&family=Permanent+Marker&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
  <title>Home</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="nav-container">
    <nav class="navbar">
      <h1 id="navbar-logo">Taniti</h1>
      <div class="menu-toggle" id="mobile-menu">
        <span class="bar"></span>
        <span class="bar"></span>
        <span class="bar"></span>
      </div>
      <ul class="nav-menu">
        <li><a href="index.html" class="nav-links">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="about.html" class="nav-links">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="transportation.html" class="nav-links">Transportation</a></li>
        <li><a href="lodging.html" class="nav-links">Lodging</a></li>
        <li><a href="food.html" class="nav-links">Food</a></li>
        <li><a href="entertainment.html" class="nav-links">Entertainment</a></li>
        <li><a href="faq.html" class="nav-links">FAQ</a></li>
        <li><a href="contact.html" class="nav-links">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
  <h1>Home</h1>
  <div class="image-container">

  </div>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

The result is not coming out anywhere near how I would like it, but I have been unable to figure out how to replicate this effectively. Does anyone have any suggestions or pointers on where I am going about this incorrectly/what I should fix?

Thanks!

Comment: if this was my project I would take that beach image in photoshop and design it with the half circle. Exactly as you see it there. I would then add <div>'Taniti'<div> as a relative position on the left hand side of the screen. I probably wouldn't spend the time designing the beach and the half circle as their own sections and play css games with it...just saying

Comment: Please make a runnable snippet so we can see how it is looking. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: You are asked to put a runnable snippet into the question, not on an external site which may disappear at any time, rendering your question useless for future readers.

Comment: I think your basic problem is one of geometry. What do you want that part circular image to look like on viewports of all sorts of different aspect ratios (long and thin, square, wide and not very high etc). Must it always be the height of the containing element? If so it sometimes won't look very round for example.

Comment: @AHaworth, thank you for your input. As this is my first attempt at this sort of project, I am aiming solely for a Desktop-viewing design (not for mobile). I agree that it would not be a good way to go for mobile. I am trying to learn more about how to position things as I design them and this has been bugging me. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
body {
  background: url('https://github.com/mcbraunie/IslandWebsite/blob/main/public/images/IslandPhotoLarge.png?raw=true') center center no-repeat;
}

Then overlay your shaped container
```